# How do I get the Jenkins WAR file to run under a different user?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, permissions

I’ve deployed the latest Jenkins WAR to a Tomcat 6 server on this flavor of Linux …

```
[daveaip-30-888-22-999 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-30-888-22-999 4.1.7-99.99.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 14 23:20:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a job that builds a Gradle project.  After the build has succeeded, I want to copy the newly-produced WAR file to the Tomcat 6 directory.  I have this shell script as an additional build step …

```
cp ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps
```

The Tomcat6 webs directory has these permissions ….

```
[daveaip-30-888-22-999 ~]$ ls -al /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
total 77876
drwxrwxr-x  4 tomcat tomcat     4096 Oct 23 19:52 .
```

But the command fails with this error …

```
+ cp ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/myproject.war’: Permission denied
```

What do I need to do to give Jenkins permissions to copy this file over?  I don’t want to change the perms of the directory to 777.

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, I added a "whoami" into the build script ...

```
whoami
cp ./build/libs/myproject.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
```

And the output was

```
+ whoami
tomcat
+ cp ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps
```

So I am already running under the user that is the owner of the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See which user running `cp ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps` command then, you can give permission to that user.
2. Run this command in `build` -> `Shell Script` section of your job's `configure`.

   ```
   $ whoami    // show the user, say 'xyz'
   ```

   then, run this command locally from teminal to change the ownership of the directory.

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R xyz: /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps  // give permission to that user
   ```
3. If two or more users needs permission to that directory, then you can create a `group` with `users`, then just give the permission to that `group`. see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337258/how-to-give-file-permission-to-a-specific-user-in-a-group)

Comment: Hey I added the "whoami" into the statement but the user that it output is alreday the user who owns the directory I'm tryihgn to copy to.

Comment: Can you try `cp -f ./build/libs/myproject.war /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps`?
and also restart the server.

Comment: see the permission of `./build/libs/myproject.war`. You can try if copy works from your jenkins terminal.

Comment: Yup, the file ownership of ./build/libs/myproject.war was the problem.  Changing that allowed everything to work.